# Use Set.Make.iter to transform the elements of a set?

Tags: data-structures, iterator, set, ocaml

I've got a library which implements a set (interface with documentation available here: http://pastebin.com/j9QUyN1G). I understand everything apart from this fragment:

```
val iter : ('a -> unit) -> 'a t -> unit 
(** [iter f s] applies [f] to all elements in set [s].  The elements
    are passed to [f] in increasing order with respect to the ordering
    used to create the set. *)
```

So `iter` takes a function as one of the arguements and applies it to all elements of set. So I would expect something like `('a -> 'a)` which takes an element of the set and changes it to element of the same type with other value or `('a -> 'b)` which takes `'a t` and transforms it to `'b t`. But instead `iter` takes a function of type `('a -> unit)` and also returns `unit`, not an `'a t` nor `'b t`.

So how should an example function passed to `iter` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iter` doesn't change the elements of the set. It's executed purely for its side effects. You might use it to print the elements, for example:

```
module StringSet = Set.Make(String)
…
StringSet.iter print_endline ss
```

The set data structure is immutable, so you can't change the elements of the set. You can build a new set whose elements are derived from an existing set. For a list, there's the function `map` which takes a list `[x1; …; xn]` and returns a new list `[f x1; …; f xn]`. There is no similar function in the `Set` module because elements in a set are not stored in the order chosen by the caller: there's no such thing as a set with its elements in an order derived from another set. If you want to build a set from the images of the elements of a set, insert the new elements one by one.

```
module Int = struct
  type t = int
  let compare = Pervasives.compare
end
module IntSet = Set.Make(Int)
module StringSet = Set.Make(String)
let int_to_string_set is =
  IntSet.fold (fun i ss -> StringSet.add (string_of_int i) ss) is StringSet.empty
```

Answer (score 1):

`iter` takes such function that accepts argument of type `'a` do with it whatever it whats and returns a value of type `unit`. In other words it is evaluated for the side-effects since it can't return anything worthwhile.

What you're looking for is a `map` function, that usually accepts a function of type `'a -> 'b` a container with elements of type `'a` and returns an container with elements of type `'b`. Unfortunately to you, the interface you've shown, doesn't provide such function. But this is not a problem, since it provides a `fold` function, that is the most general iterator. Having only `fold` you can implement any other iteratos, like `map`, `iter`, `exists`, etc... Indeed in `Core` library you can find `Container.Make` functor that will automatically derive a common container interface from only one function - `fold`. But also, you can define map by yourself:

```
let map f xs =
  fold (fun x ys -> add (f x) ys) xs empty
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be a function with side effects, like this:

```
Let p x = Printf.printf "%d\n" x
```